# Choosing grad_norm() value

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

Is there's any technique to choose the best grad_norm() value by looking at the hidden weights? As trying different value takes a lot of time, I was wondering if anyone knows it and share their knowledge here.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Just making sure, no pun intended: are you absolutely sure you need it? AFAIK it's kinda hacky yet useful for RNN-like architectures

Comment: As, I just saw my under-fit model started to have a consistent-performance bar rise a bit after including grad_norm(), I realized having a good knowledge about it might fast-track me to achieving better results.